# Поля IsSpecified при генерации класса

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Как настраивается генерация классов при добавлении Service Reference?
Стоят рядом два компьютера, на них с одного дистрибутива установленная VS2013, открыт один и тот же проект, в который добавляется ссылка на один и тот же сервис. Одна студия генерирует поля `IsSpecified`, другая - атрибут `[System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()]`.
Хотелось бы добиться одинакового поведения.

Comment: Если еще актуально - стоит сравнить файлы `Reference.svcmap`, которые получились в результате. Результат контролируется опциями `svcutil` (`/targetClientVersion:Version30`/`35`), возможно, на разных машинах просто разные настройки по умолчанию.

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Действительно, через Reference.svcmap можно настроить. Регулируется опцией Serializer, значение DataContractSerializer генерит атрибуты, XmlSerializer - поля IsSpecified. Если не затруднит, оформите комментарий как ответ.

Comment: угадал :) оформил как ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add Reference (и используемая внутри утилита svcutil) поддерживает два разных сериализатора.

- `DataContractSerializer` генерует атрибуты `OptionalFieldAttribute`
- `XmlSerializer` - поля `IsSpecified`

По умолчанию студия/svcutil пытается выбрать сериализатор в зависимости от описания сервиса. У `DataContractSerializer` [есть некоторые ограничения](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733112.aspx), поэтому при малейшем подозрении студия переключается на `XmlSerializer`.

Возможно, проверяемые при этом условия чуть-чуть отличаются на разных машинах, и студия использует разыне сериализаторы.

Явно указать сериализатор можно в элементе `<Serializer>` в файле `Reference.svcmap`. Значение по умолчанию - `Auto`.

Соответствующий параметр svcutil - [`/serializer:`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733(v=vs.110).aspx)